# Observable not emitting new values

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, angular, rxjs

I am trying to use angular 2 with firebase and i have managed to push data to firebase and get the back but when i try to add new data to firebase they are not reflected in the .get observable automatically - have to refresh page or switch between routes, is this the correct behavior? if not what should i do to automatically update view with new values as they come?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "angular2/core";
import { FirebaseService } from "../shared/firebase.service";
import { ArcItem } from "./arc-item.model";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { KeysPipe } from "../shared/keys.pipe";

@Component({
    selector: "arc-list",
    template: `
    <ul class="arc-list">
      <li *ngFor="#item of listItems | async | keys" class="arc-item">
        <h3>{{ item.name}}</h3><a [href]="item.resourceUrl" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success pull-right"><span>Go</span></a>
        <hr>
        <blockquote>{{ item.description }}</blockquote>
        <hr>
      </li>
    </ul>
    `,
    pipes: [KeysPipe]

})

export class ArcListComponent implements OnInit {
  listItems: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private _firebaseService: FirebaseService) {}

  ngOnInit(): any {
    this.listItems = this._firebaseService.getResources();
  }

}
```

firebase.service

```
import { Injectable } from "angular2/core";
import { Http } from "angular2/http";
import { ArcItem } from "../arc/arc-item.model";
import "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  setResource(id: number, title: string, description: string, resourceUrl: string) {
    const body = JSON.stringify({ id: id, title: title, description: description, resourceUrl: resourceUrl});

    return this._http
                     .post("https://#####.firebaseio.com/resource.json", body)
                     .map(response => response.json());
  }

  getResources() {
    return this._http
                     .get("https://#####.firebaseio.com/resource.json")
                     .map(response => response.json());

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it's normal since you need to subscribe to the `child_added` event to be automatically notified when you add an element:

```
let firebaseRef = new Filebase('https://####.firebaseio-demo.com/resource');
firebaseRef.on('child_added', (childSnapshot, prevChildKey) => {
  childSnapshot.forEach((records) => {
    this.listItems.push(records.val());
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there a version of your code without the Firebase library? as i am just using the rest api of firebase.

Comment: In fact, without this, you need to call explicitly the `getResources` method when you receive the response of `setResource` (in the callback subscribed on the observable returned by `setResource`)... Hoping that I correctly understand your use case.

Comment: i will try that thank you but calling getResources each time won't fetch all data instead of just the one added or?